# How can I solve $\sum_{b=0}^{\frac{k}{\sqrt{x}}}\sum_{a=1}^{x} \frac{aF(r\sqrt{a^2+b^2})}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=cF(\delta(x+l))$ for the function $F(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, summation, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

How can I solve $\sum_{b=0}^{\frac{k}{\sqrt{x}}}\sum_{a=1}^{x} \frac{aF(r\sqrt{a^2+b^2})}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=cF(\delta(x+l))$ for the function $F(x)$, where $k$, $r$, $c$, $\delta$ and $l$ are constants, and $a$, $b$ are indices? Is it possible to solve?

I encountered the problem above while trying to solve a rather difficult physics/mechanics problem, and I am particularly interested in what the graph of $F(x)$ looks like (I am aware that a closed-form solution for $F(x)$ may not exist judging from how ghastly the original equation looks).

I have tried attacking this from many different angles, including an attempt to 'undo' the summations on the left-hand side by applying the property $\sum_{n=a}^{x} f(n) = g(x) \implies f(x) = g(x)-g(x-1)$ twice, but I was left with yet another functional equation that I had no idea how to tackle. I also tried turning the left-hand side into a double integral instead (I guessed that this would perhaps give the approximate shape of the function) and then differentiating both sides twice using the chain rule, but this lead to yet another functional differential equation that I did not know how to solve. In each case, I tried to use a series solution of the form $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$, my attempt spread across pages of tedious algebra, but to no avail. Needless to say, I'm quite stuck at this stage and don't know how to proceed. Through experimentation on Desmos, I have found that functions of the form $F(x) = x^{-n} - x^{-(n+1)}$ seem to work (where $n$ is a positive integer), but I have no clue as to whether this is correct in general, or how to arrive at such a result.

I would greatly appreciate any tips or insight into the nature of this pretty elusive problem (although an answer may be more obvious to most people than to me).

Thanks

Comment: My first try for such a problem would be to try to find free graphing software, and graph the function $F(x)$, to try to understand its behavior visually.  I suggest googling on "free graphics software wikipedia".

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I'm actually trying to solve for the function $F$ in the equation above, so I'm not sure how I'd graph $F(x)$ without knowing what it is explicitly equal to.

Comment: Could be worth to look at special cases, e.g. $c=0$ and/or $r=0$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the nature of $x$? Is it an integer? If it is, the sum may need to be  modified since $k/\sqrt{x}$ is usually not an integer. Generally this equation needs some love to make sense.

Comment: You are right, I didn't read your question closely enough.  Personally, my first try would be to set $F(x) = b_3x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x^1 + b_0$.  Then, I  would set $h_1(x) = $ the LHS and $h_2(x) = $ the RHS, and $H(x) = h_1(x) - h_2(x).$  Then, I would try to fine tune the coefficients $b_3, b_2, b_1, b_0$ so that $H(x)$ approached being constantly $0$.  ...see next comment.

Comment: My thinking is : "I encountered the problem above while trying to solve a rather difficult physics/mechanics problem" : In nature, what functions typically accurately describe the corresponding physics/mechanics *situations*?  Is it $3$-rd degree polynomials, functions of the form $F(x) = C_1e^{k_1x} + C_2e^{-k_2x} + C_3\cos(k_3x) + C_4\sin(k_4x),$ or what?  If you find the *form* of a function that typically represents the real world situation, that could be a good *first step*.

Comment: Replying to DinosaurEgg: $x$ is any real number greater than zero. I know that it doesn't make much sense to have a non-integer as a bound for summations, but graphing calculators like Desmos seem to have no trouble computing them as they just round the value of $\frac{k}{\sqrt{x}}$ up or down, but perhaps this may need amending.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll give the cubic a try.